# How to get data using Google finance API

Tags: stocks, stock, stockquotes

http://www.google.com/finance?q=nse%3Areliance

Is it possible to get real-time data (price and volume) using Google API ?

Any sample code (C++/C#) would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this project : [Implementation of Google Finance API in C#](http://code.google.com/p/googlefinance/) , it has also a demo of how to use it.

You may also check Yahoo finance API , [here's a sample](http://madskristensen.net/post/Stock-quote-class-in-C.aspx) of how to get real-time data from it  in C#

Answer (score 1):

This might be a good starting point: http://code.google.com/intl/de/apis/finance/.
Here you can find a client library for .NET to make the access at the Google Data Protocol easier: http://code.google.com/intl/de/apis/gdata/docs/client-libraries.html